# ImportError: cannot import name 'image_dataset_from_directory' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Why am i getting this issue? I can import image module from kera.preprocessing. But cannot import image_dataset_from_directory. TF version: 1.14

Comment: I do not think that is available in TF 1.14 so you will have to upgrade to the latest version which is TF 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix it by updating TensorFlow using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

At the time of answering(the latest TensorFlow version is 2.4.1) and if you simply upgrade your tensorflow then issue will be resolved, also no need to install `tf-nightly`

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```