# Cannot import name 'load_img' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Why am I getting this issue? I can import image module from `kera.preprocessing`. But cannot import `image_dataset_from_directory`. My TensorFlow version is 2.9.1, so I am not dealing with an old version, e.g. [ImportError: cannot import name 'image_dataset_from_directory' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690693/importerror-cannot-import-name-image-dataset-from-directory-from-tensorflow)

```
# make a prediction for a new image.
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

# load and prepare the image
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 3 channels
    img = img.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
    # center pixel data
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img - [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    return img

# load an image and predict the class
def run_example():
    # load the image
    img = load_image('test.jpg')
    # load model
    model = load_model('final_model.h5')
    # predict the class
    result = model.predict(img)
    print(result[0])

# entry point, run the example
run_example()
```

error

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_img' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'
```

Answer (score 29):

`keras.preprocessing` API is deprecated in Tensorflow 2.9.1. Please use `tf.keras.utils` instead, to import `load_img` as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img
```

To load dataset from directories please use
`tensorflow.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`. For more details, please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing).

Comment: from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img # tf is an abbrev

Answer (score 6):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
```

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
    from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
```

with

```
    from keras_preprocessing.image import load_img
```