# bad: keras library in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'
here is the error that appears when I try to load an image and I don't understand why?

from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img
I tried to import this library but without success[my fonction who have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqgTA.png)

Comment: `load`, not `laod`.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img' the same error

Comment: Oh, because that's in a different module. [`keras.utils.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'load\_img' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479044/cannot-import-name-load-img-from-keras-preprocessing-image)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for using

```
keras.preprocessing.image
```

??

If not, You can use

```
   from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory
```

Also, please make sure you are on the up-to-date version on TF, unless your work requires v1.X

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

Comment: my version is 2.12.0